# Why by defining another pointer cells whole code stops working?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm trying to transpose the matrix 'a' into 'b' but before making the line of defining b a comment by putting '//' actually nothing happens while running the code but after that code works until somewhere...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double **a , **b;
void print(double **);
void ma();
int i , j , d;

int main()
{
   d = 2;
   a = new double *[d];
   for (i = 0 ; i < d ; i++)
   {
      a [i] = new double [d];
      b [i] = new double [d];
   }
   for (i = 0 ; i < d ; i++)
     for (j = 0 ; j < d ; j++)
           a[i][j] = i + j ;
   print(a);
   ma();
   print(b);
   delete []a;
   delete []b;  
 }

 void ma () {
    cout << "here";
     for (i = 0 ; i < d ; i++)
        for (j = 0 ; j < d ; j++)
            b[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }

  void print (double **a) {
       cout << "here";
       cout << "\n\n";
       for(i = 0 ; i < d ; i++)
       {
            for (j = 0 ; j < d ; j++)
               cout << "\t\t" << a[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << "\n";
       }
       cout << "\n\n"; 
  }
```

Comment: `b [i] = new double [d];` is undefined behaviour as you need to initialise `b` like you did `a` just before the first loop.  However use `std::vector<double>` and remove all the C-style arrays together with all the `new` and `delete`s

Comment: `a` is initialised using `a = new double *[d]`.    There needs to be a similar initialisation of `b`.   There isn't, so all usage of `b[i]`, etc have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Incidentally, `delete [] a` and `delete [] b` are insufficient to clean up.   There also needs to be a loop to `delete [] a[i]` and `delete [] b[i]`.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard I forget about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see, you declare b `double **b` but never call a new on it in your code? You do this for a:

`a = new double *[d];`

Perhaps this will resolve the issue?

Comment: ((((: I'm coding for 2 days continually and 5 hours of sleep and this is the result ;)))))